# How can I change column names in R in imported dataset so they don't just show on console but are permanent?

Tags: r

//   I was trying to rename my column using rename() but it only shows up in console but not in the dataset itself when I View() it.

```
daily_intensities%>%
  rename(NotActive=SedentaryMinutes)
View(daily_intensities)
```

After View() it still shows SedentaryMintues.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Would be a good idea to show us some of your code. Is it possible you're not saving back the result of your `rename` to your data? For example, if `x` contains `'test'` it will still be just `'test'` after `toupper(x)`. To replace the value of `x` we'd say `x <- toupper(x)`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the new column labels in list like so and pass it to the colnames:

```
colnames(df) <- c('newName1','newName2','newName3')
```

Or if its just one column:

```
names(df)[names(df) == 'oldName1'] <- 'newName1'
```